# Using Order By in IN condition

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error

Let's say we have this silly query:

```
Select * From Emp Where Id In (Select Id From Emp)
```

Let's do a small modification inside `IN` condition by adding an `Order By` clause.

```
Select * From Mail Where Id In (Select Id From Mail Order By Id)
```

Then we are getting the following error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Oracle assumes that IN condition will end after declaring the From table. As a result waits for right parenthesis, but we give an Order By instead.
Why can't we add an Order By inside IN condition?

**FYI**: I don't ask for a equivalent query. This is an example after all. I just can't understand why this error occurs.

Comment: I assume the reason is that having an ORDER BY inside an IN does not change the result of the IN, so it was forbidden

Comment: never mind 'how' could you'- 'why' would you - what do you think you will gain from adding that order by?

Comment: @mp3ferret indeed, adding an order by provides no benefit

Comment: You are right, there is no benefit. But instead of getting an expensive query we are getting a query with an error. This would be too strict in my point of view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the condition `x in (select something from somewhere)`. It returns true if `x` is equal to any of the `something`s returned from the query - regardless of whether it's the first, second, last, or anything in the middle. The order that the `something`s are returned is inconsequential. Adding an `order by` clause to a query often comes with a hefty performance hit, so I'm guessing this this limitation was introduced to prevent adding a clause that has no impact on the query's correctness on the one hand and may be quite expensive on the other.

Answer (score 1):

It would not make sense to sort the values inside the **IN** clause. Think in this way:

```
IN (a, b, c)
```

is same as

```
IN (c, b, a)
```

IS SAME AS

```
IN (b, c, a)
```

Internally Oracle applies **OR** condition, so it is equivalent to:

```
WHERE id = a OR id = b OR id = c
```

Would it make any sense to order the conditions?

Ordering comes at it's own expense. So, when there is no need to sort, just don't do it. And in this case, Oracle applied the same rule.

When it comes to performance of the query, optimizer needs choose the best possible execution plan i.e. with the least cost to achieve the desired output. ORDER BY is useless in this case, and *Oracle did a good job to prevent using it at all*.

For the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm),

> ```
> Type of Condition   Operation
> -----------------   ----------
> IN                  Equal-to-any-member-of test. Equivalent to =ANY.
> ```

So, when you need to test **ANY** value for membership in a list of values, there is no need of ordered list, just a random matching does the job.

Comment: My impression was that the optimizer would ignore this nonsense Order By instead of not permitting at all.

Comment: @istovatis Yes, of course. That's why I said *Oracle did a good job to prevent using it at all.* Also, if you read the link to the documentation I gave, it explains beautifully the algorithm it uses for matching the value for membership.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at Oracle SQL reference (syntax diagrams) you will find a reason. ORDER BY is part of "select" statement, while `IN` clause uses lover level "subquery" statement. Your problem relates to nature of the Oracle's SQL grammar.

PS: there might be more gotchas like multiple `UNION`, `MINUS` on "subqueries" and then also you can use ONLY one `ORDER BY` clause, as this applies only onto result of `UNION` operation.
This will fail too:

```
select * from dual order by 1
union all
select * from dual order by 1;
```